# Sass mixins for font information

Tags: css, sass

I was wondering if anyone had come across this.

I'm creating something that uses the same font across different divs, and as such, was going to put the font info into a mixin.

I've attached the code below, but my compiler doesn't seem to like it.

any help would be appreciated!

```
@mixin twinpeaksfont {
font-family: arial;
font-size: 80px;
padding-top: 30px;
color:#5e3a38;
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 1.25px;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: #2ab650;
}



#title {
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    @include twinpeaksfont;
  }

}
```

Comment: my compiler seems to like it, does any error ocure for you?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Please include the error message in your question.

Comment: Try autoprefixer for those vendor prefix, https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it wants the parenthesis?

```
@mixin twinpeaksfont() {
font-family: arial;
font-size: 80px;
padding-top: 30px;
color:#5e3a38;
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 1.25px;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: #2ab650;
}



#title {
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    @include twinpeaksfont;
  }

}
```

With or without the parenthesis, it's working at [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/4h6y45dd/1/)